# Octave comet3 cannot be plotted

Tags: octave

I have Octave 4.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 with installed geometry 3.0.0 package.
When I try to compile the [example code](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/comet3.html) with comet3 function, I receive only empty coordinate system without any animation:

[image]

Can you help me diagnose the error? Ubuntu is pretty new for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Did you install the software and the package from the official repository?

Comment: I downloaded Octave from [this repository](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/) and installed via 'make install'. Geometry package is downloaded from [official repository](https://octave.sourceforge.io/geometry/) and installed via 'pkg install'.

Comment: What you linked is not a repository, it's a FTP archive with source code. Please first try to remove Octave and install it from the official Ubuntu repositories and see if it gives the same problem.

Comment: I reinstalled Octave (apparently 4.0.2) from official repository and still no animation when compiling `comet3`.

Comment: I also tried to switch my graphic cards with no success. Please help. I'm missing such a great tool which is Octave.